# Stop R studio from jumping to the next function

Tags: rstudio

There's this one issue with Rstudio that has been bothering me for a long while now and I cannot find a solution.
I like to use a lot of shortcuts and move around the editor with arrow keys and also scroll the editor using Ctrl + arrow shorts. The issue is that if the script contains a user defined function and I press Ctrl+Up/Down the cursor jumps to that function even if it's nowhere near. Like sometimes hundreds of lines. EXTREMELY ANNOYING!!! And I have looked through shortcuts and this is the only thing I have found:
[image]

There are no more different Ctrl+Up/Down shorts. So it doesn't seem to be a multi mapping issue. Also if I change this mapping to something else the annoying jumping still continues. I just want it to stop! Can anybody help? Doesn't it annoy anyone else?

Comment: What is the behaviour you expect/want from Ctrl+Down/Up?

Comment: Try defining a new section in your document, like so: ```##### Section #####```. You can also use `----- Another section -----`.

Comment: CTRL+^ is supposed to keep the cursor where it is and then scroll up a line, what he means and what happens is that the cursor moves to the first defined user function instead and from there pressing it again it scrolls as supposed to be. The initial jump should never been made.

Comment: I can't understand how this doesn't drive everyone crazy. I've always guessed maybe that the behavior is different on a Mac, which seems to be the platform for the devs.

Comment: Speaking of workarounds, I've become very diligent about not defining functions in any script even if they're just used once or if they're in an apply or mapping function. I also smash all the commands into a single line whenever possible, to avoids the curly braces.

Comment: So this is the solution? Avoid? :D

Comment: any news? have you written the creators of Rstudio?

Answer (score 3):

The behaviour of RStudio where Ctrl+Up and Ctrl+Down step the cursor between function definitions is not configurable and cannot be changed. Oddly, the same pair of keystrokes were chosen to move the scroll bar.

Your only option to avoid the conflict is to redefine the scroll up and scroll down keystrokes to something else (e.g. F8/F9 or something) so that they not longer conflict with this hardcoded option. You can then control the scroll bar using the keystrokes you have chosen without it conflicting with the behaviour where it steps between functions.

If you find you have accidentally navigated to a function you didn't want using Ctrl+Down, you can return the cursor to where it was using the "Source Navigate Back" keystroke which defaults to Ctrl+F9.

IMO this is clearly a bug in RStudio. I would report it to them and hope that it is fixed for a future version.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Just to clarify both of your points- I expect Ctrl+Up/Down to scroll or do nothing if I re-assign that option. I don't particularly care for scrolling with keyboard (it is slightly useful tho) but I so often "mis-click" Ctrl+Up/Down and suddenly I'm somewhere totally wrong and have to look up where I left off. :(

Comment: You can navigate back to where you were using the Ctrl+F9 keystroke

Comment: that is a nice workaround but not a solution :)

Comment: @Gunnar: Indeed, sadly there is no current real fix. All you can do is report it and ask them to fix it (or, if you have the skills, fix it yourself and submit a pull request I guess), or cope with a workaround for now.

Comment: This is still an issue. This behaviour is unbelievably annoying.